# Bash script create database

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, terminal, command

I've created a bash script to install Wordpress locally and create the database on my local machine.

This part should normally create the database

```
mysql -u $dbuser -p $dbpass "create database '$dbname'"
```

But I getting this error:

```
mysql: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: Either you don't have the mysql client installed, or your PATH can't find it. Also, you shouldn't use single-quotes to delimit the database name in your SQL statement. Also you must use `-p$dbpass` with no space in the middle.

Comment: This is my command right now: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
mysql -u$dbuser -p$dbpass "create database $dbname"

I'm using a mac

Comment: `create database if not exists $dbname` might also be a useful construct to prevent errors if the database already exists.

Comment: What on Earth is the `mysql` argument doing after `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`?

Comment: @l0b0, The argument names the schema to use as the default schema. Though it's not necessary for this command, because you don't need to be "in" a schema to run `create database`.

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
mysql -u$dbuser -p$dbpass "create database if not exists $dbname"

But still error: mysql: command not found

Comment: This issue will always be the path of mysql. I have MAMP installed on my computer. So mysql is located somewhere in the application folder.

But on someone elses computer, it will probably located somewhere else. So I'm unable to make it work for everyone, I think.

Answer (score 0):

check mysql command exists or not:

```
$ sudo updatedb && locate bin/mysql
/usr/local/src/mysql/bin/mysql
```

then:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/src/mysql/bin/
```

you can install updatedb and locate commands as:

```
#debian based
apt install mlocate
#centos
yum install mlocate
```